# Vibration and notification commands not working

Tags: android, timertask

I am working on an application for fire alarm. Basically what I am trying to do is create a background service which will notify user and vibrate device when the specific website is up. That website is created by a Node mcu which is triggered by smoke or flame sensor. I am new to android studio but after some research I have written the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Tried to debug it but failed can anyone tell me what is going wrong ???

Here is the code which I wrote for the service -

```
 public class ExampleService extends Service {
    int flag=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Fire Alarm Service")
                .setContentText("Alarm system is functional")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();


        Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isInternetAvailable()){
                    flag = 1;
                }else{
                    flag = 0;
                }
                System.out.println("pingHost flag: " + flag );
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (flag == 1) {
                            startForeground(1, notification);
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(5000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                            } else {
                                //deprecated in API 26
                                v.vibrate(5000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 10000);


        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
 public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
            //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Both Vibration and Notification commands work outside Timertask so I tried to run code outside timer task but it doesn't seem to work. Also that flag and Is internet available logic is working properly....
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You've put the `startForeground()` call and vibration stuff into a `Runnable` in a new `Thread`, but you never `start()` that `Thread`. Why are you creating a new `Thread` there? It seems unnecessary. I would also mention that, if you're running on an Android version >= API level 26, `startForeground()` should be called pretty much immediately, rather than after some indeterminate delay. Obviously, this will show your `Notification` immediately, as well, so you might use some other indication for the internet availability, such as changing the `Notification`'s text.

Comment: Ok I will remove that thread but I want that notification to pop up only when conditions are true. Any alternative? Also vibrate command not working... @Mike M.

Comment: You can run a regular `Service` for a few minutes on Oreo+, but the system will eventually stop it unless your app is in the foreground. You should have a read through [this developer page info](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services). I'm not sure what you mean by "vibrate command not working". Your question states that it worked outside of the `TimerTask`. The issue with the posted code is that it was just not being executed. It shouldn't matter if it's called in a `TimerTask` or not.

Comment: That was the issue here. I was trying to figure out why that code was not getting executed but any was I finally made it working by creating a method and putting notification and vibration commands in it and then calling it from timer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :
I did some changes after debugging and now the code is working. Dont know why previously it wasn't but still all good now. Thanks!

Code after change is :-

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
    int flag2=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isInternetAvailable()){
                    flag2 = 1;
                }else{
                    flag2 = 0;
                }
                System.out.println("pingHost flag2: " + flag2 );
                if (flag2 == 1) {
                    notif();
                }
            }
    }, 0, 10000);

        return START_STICKY; }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
            //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void notif() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Fire Alarm Service")
                .setContentText("Fire Detected in D building")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(5000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            //deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(5000);
        }
    }
}
```